# Shell Scripting Arithmetic Operators for Comparison

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, comparison, operators

I am trying to learn shell scripting and following the tutorials on tutorialspoint when I came across this problem with arithmetic comparison.

```
$VAL1=10
$VAL2=20
$VAL3=10

if [ $VAL1 == $VAL2 ]
then
    echo "equal"
else
    echo "not equal"
fi
```

but I got a `[: ==: unexpected operator` I am not sure why the comparison operator did not work. I know I can also use rational operators, but I want to know why '==' is not defined.

Comment: as your title says ksh (but your tag says bash) , you can use `==` inside of `(( ... == ... ))` tests (which I also believe are OK in bash). Good luck.

Comment: @Jack: Did the answer solved the problem? If so, can you please accept it to mark the question as solved?

Answer (score 11):

You want to change it to:

```
VAL1=10
VAL2=20
VAL3=10

if [ "$VAL1" -eq "$VAL2" ]
then
    echo "equal"
else
    echo "not equal"
fi
```

**Explanations:**

- Don't add the `$` for the lvalue (variable being assigned) in an assignment.
- Always wrap your variables with double-quotes in tests. The `[: ==: unexpected operator` error you got is because, since `VAL1` / `VAL2` were not assigned properly earlier, ksh expansion of your test actually ends up resolving to this: `if [ == ]` - (but you see that it's actually not a problem about `==` being undefined)
- Use the following for numeric comparisons instead of the `==` notation:

  - `-eq` (==)
  - `-ne` (!=)
  - `-gt` (>)
  - `-ge` (>=)
  - `-lt` (<)
  - `-le` (<=)

Comment: @Jack np =) if you've found the answer useful, you can upvote it / accept it!